# Trigger que al insertar más de 6 registros simultáneos, dé un error, ya que solo se permiten agregar hasta 5 registros

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito crear un trigger en SQL que al insertar más de 6 registros simultáneos, dé un error, ya que solo se permiten agregar hasta 5 registros. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer eso?

Comment: Claro que si, pero necesitas tu leer [ask] y de paso hacer el [tour] y nosotros recibir de ti por favor un ejemplo de lo que hayss intentado y que motor de bases de datos usas

Comment: ¿En qué motor de base de datos trabajas?

Comment: @jachguate SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

En SQL Server puedes valerte de un trigger `instead of insert` para lograr tu propósito. Dado que los triggers en SQL Server solo pueden ejecutarse para cada operación completa (y no fila por fila como en otros motores) tienes, de hecho, un escenario más sencillo.

Hay que contar los registros que vienen en la pseudo tabla `inserted` y si son más de los que debes permitir, lanzar un mensaje de error y no insertar nada a la tabla:

Acá dejo un ejemplo completo con una tabla simple que tiene un solo campo. Primero creo la tabla:

```
create table PruebaLimite (
  Valor int not null primary key
);
go
```

Luego el trigger que realiza la verificación:

```
create trigger LimitarPruebaLimite on PruebaLimite instead of insert 
as
begin
  declare @Limite int = 5;
  declare @Contador int;
  select @Contador = count(1) from Inserted;
  if @Contador <= @Limite 
  begin
    set nocount on;
    insert into PruebaLimite select * from Inserted;
    set nocount off;
  end
  else
    raiserror('No puede insertar más de %d registros a la vez', 16, 1, @Limite);
end
go
```

Finalmente, lanzo una instrucción de inserción que tiene más de 5 registros:

```
insert into PruebaLimite 
values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8);
```

Lo que me devuelve esto:

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure LimitarPruebaLimite, Line 15 [Batch Start Line 24]
No puede insertar más de 5 registros a la vez

(8 rows affected)

Completion time: 2020-08-04T13:14:31.2192353-06:00
```

Para finalizar, podrías realizar la misma validación en un trigger `after insert` y forzar un `rollback` si hay error, que es lo que mucha gente hace, pero en realidad es una solución *sucia*. Si hay un problema de validación de datos, lo mejor es que esos datos nunca toquen la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es algo que normalmente no harías en un trigger sino desde el código de la aplicación. De esa forma, evitas enviar información entre el cliente, el servidor web y el servidor de base de datos.

Sin embargo, esto se hace contando las filas de la tabla virtual `inserted`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TI_MiTabla ON dbo.MiTabla
FOR INSERT
AS

IF  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted) > 5
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
    THROW  51000, 'No se pueden insertar más de cinco registros simultaneos', 1;
END;
GO
```